# Sylow $7$-subgroup of a group of order $4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

How to show that the sylow $7$-subgroup of a group of order $420$ is normal. I Know that it is true using GAP. But how to show it without using GAP. I don't know how to start this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The goal is to show that there is exactly one Sylow 7 subgroup. With that you can use Sylow's second theorem to conclude it's normal. To show that it is the only one use the third theorem to conclude that the number of them must be 1 or 15. Then rule out 15.

Comment: @TheNumber23 How to rule out 15? I think this is the most crucial part.

Comment: Also the sylow $7-$subgroup is normal in any group of order $2.3.5.7$ or $3.5.7$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we need to eliminate the possibility of $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups in the group $G$ with $|G|=420$. Assume that happens. Then, for $P \in {\rm Syl}_7(G)$,we have $|N_G(P)|=28$, and so there exists $t \in N_G(P)$ of order $2$ centralizing $P$.

Now consider the action of $G$ by conjugation on the set of $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups. Then the point stabilizer $N_G(P)$ has an element of order $7$ which must act as two $7$-cycles.

Now there are two possibilities for the action of $t$. Firstly, it could fix all $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups. (Thanks for comment from @jpvee for pointing that out.) In that case it is in the kernel of the action. Since the image of the action in $S_{15}$ is transitive and has stabilizer of order divisible by $7$, its order is $105$ or $210$. We shall see below that groups of these orders have normal (and hence unique) Sylow $7$-subgroups, which is a contradiction, because we are assuming that there are $15$.

The second possibility is that $t$  interchange the two $7$-cycles, so $t$ acts as an odd permutation. Now by intersecting with the alternating group, we find that $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ of index $2$, so $|H|=210$, and it is sufficient to prove that $H$ has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup.

Since $H$ has twice odd order, by considering its regular permutation representation and intersecting with the alternating group, we find that $H$ also has a normal subgroup $K$ of index $2$, and it is sufficient to solve the same problem for $K$, which has order $105$.

Now if $K$ has $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, then we have $90$ elements of order $7$, so there are only $15$ more elements in total. Hence $K$ must have a unique and therefore normal Sylow $5$-subgroup, and since this has no automorphism of order $7$, it is centralized by a Sylow $7$-subgroup $P$, so $|N_K(P)| \ge 35$, contradiction.

Comment: Just a small note: In your analysis of the action of $N_G(P)$ and the Sylow $7$-subgroups, $t$ could also fix all of them; in which case it would be centralizing the group generated by all Sylow $7$-subgroups. But then we'd have a group of order $210$ or $420$ with a normal subgroup of order $2$, so looking at the factor group (and applying the rest or your arguments) gives the desired result.

Comment: @jpvee: Thanks! I missed that point. I was adapting a proof I had already that a group of order $420$ is not simple, which was assuming a faithful action.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: $t$ would consist of $7$ transpositions, and so it would be an odd permutation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of ruling out the case that $G$ contains $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups.

Assume the contrary, and let $S$ be one of those $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups. Then $N:=N_G(S)$ has order$28$, in particular, no element of order 5 normalizes (much less centralizes) $S$. This implies that no Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$, so by Sylow's theorem, the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups must be $21$. Let $F$ by a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$. Then similarly, any element of order $3$ centralizes neither $S$ nor $F$, so again by Sylow, $35$ must divide the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups which therefore has to be $70$.

In particular, $G$ contains $15*6=90$ elements of order $7$, $21*4=84$ elements of order $5$ and $70*2=140$ elements of order $3$.

Next we look at the structure of $N$. Since $|Aut(S)|=6$, $C_N(S)$ contains (at least) one element $t$ of order $2$ and therefore $N$ contains at least $6$ elements of order $14$. If one such element $x$ were contained in a conjugate $N^g$ other than $N$, then $S=<x^2>\leq N^g=N_G(S^g)$ and therefore $S=S^g$ contradicting $N^g\neq N$. Therefore $G$ contains at least $15*6=90$ elements of order $14$.

Likewise, by looking at the structure of the normalizer of $F$, we see that $G$ contains at least $21*4=84$ elements of order $6$.

In total, the number of elements of $G$ of orders $1$, $7$, $5$, $3$, $14$ or $6$ is $1+90+84+140+90+84=489>420=|G|$, a clear contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: If $t$ centralizes $S$ then $N$ surely contains $7-1=6$ elements of order $14$, but where does the $7$th element of order $14$ come from?

Comment: @Anvita: Oops, you are quite right - I'll try to modify the proof - hopefully, it can be saved.